# make: *** No rule to make target 'watch_scss'. Stop

Tags: makefile

When I run `make watch_scss` from terminal - 
I have got an error: `make: *** No rule to make target 'watch_scss'.  Stop.`

Could you help me please?

Here is my **MakeFile**:

```
watch_scss:
    sass --watch src/static/scss/:public/styles/css/

minify:
    cleancss public/styles/css/main.css -o public/styles/css/main.min.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `make -f MakeFile watch_scss` instead of just `make watch_scss`. Or (which is perhaps more along the lines of what you wanted) rename `MakeFile` to `Makefile` (or what your version of make expects). From GNU make [man page](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/make.1.html#DESCRIPTION):

> `make` executes commands in the `makefile` to update one or more target
>          names, where name is typically a program.  If no `-f` option is
>          present, `make` will look for the makefiles `GNUmakefile`, `makefile`, and
>          `Makefile`, in that order.

Note that case does matter.

Comment: Thanks. As additional also I have should install sass globally